# Best Practices for "temporary" accounts in a Windows server environment?

Tags: windows-server-2003, accounts, guest

Are there any best practices for "temporary worker" accounts in a Windows server environment?

We have a couple of contractors joining the organization temporarily.  They only need access to a few folders.

Aside from joining them to the "Domain Guests" group and granting them access only to the folders specified.  Are there any other issues to be aware of?

We are in a Windows Server 2003 domain environment.

Answer (score 4):

If you know when they will be leaving, the Account Expiration attribute is worth exploring.

Comment: +1, Even if you don't know, set if for 2 weeks (or whatever reasonable time period) and put a post-it on your monitor to keep extending that every 2 weeks.

Comment: thanks!  their enrollment does not have a "set" enddate.  It is rolling.

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention email, so maybe they don't need it, which will save some hassle.  When we've had temporary contractors that needed to send email, we usually set up generic accounts for them (e.g. marketing-assistant) and hoped to re-use them if that department needed contractors in the future.

You probably want to keep track of which workstations they'll use (and possibly restrict them to logging in to specific machines) and remember to delete their profiles after they've gone.

Printing: you might also want to limit them to specific printers.

Comment: thanks!  they don't need email or in-house printing.  they just need access to specific folders.

I guess I was wondering if there was specific significance between the Domain Users group and the Domain Guests group.